# How to replace some characters of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, replace, tuples

I have this list of tuples (POS tag) and I need to change some characters, only if they are in the second element os the tuple:

For example:

```
x = [('We', 'PRP'), ("'re", 'VBP'), ('really', 'RB$'), ('sorry', 'JJ'), ('...', ':')]
```

I need to change the "strange" character of the second element, in this example: RB$ and :.

I have tried:

```
x_2[x.index(':')] = 'Dts'
```

and

```
x_2[x_2.index[,('$')]] = 'S'
```

I expect this output:

```
x_2 = [('We', 'PRP'), ("'re", 'VBP'), ('really', 'RBS'), ('sorry', 'JJ'), ('...', 'Dts')]
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if it is a really basic question, I pretty new with python.

Comment: By what logic does `':'` maps to `'Dts'`? Is there some logic behind it or an arbitrary set of rules you need to hardcode?

Comment: Your code defines `x` as the list of tuples, but then refers to `x_2`.  What is `x_2`?

Comment: By no logic, it is random.
x_2 is the try to change the characters in x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
x1 = [(i,j.replace('$','S').replace(':','Dts')) for i,j in x]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[('We', 'PRP'), ("'re", 'VBP'), ('really', 'RBS'), ('sorry', 'JJ'), ('...', 'Dts')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a translation table. In Python 3, you can use the [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) method from the `str` class:

```
change = str.maketrans({"$": "S", ":": "Dts"})
```

Which allows you to map the values in a string with the translation table by calling [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
[(i, j.translate(change)) for i,j in x]
# [('We', 'PRP'), ("'re", 'VBP'), ('really', 'RBS'), ('sorry', 'JJ'), ('...', 'Dts')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure *why* such strings should be changed so I do not know the logic for changing them, but I would just keep a dictionary of what needs to be changed (unless there is different logic and many more strings need be changed than just in this example)

```
to_change = {
    ':': 'Dts', 
    'RB$': 'RBS'
}
```

and then change them

```
x_2 = [(f, to_change.get(s, s)) for f,s in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this:

```
a, b = zip(*x) # unzip into two lists
b = list(b) # make b a list, not a tuple, in order to be mutable

'''
change values
'''
b[b.index(':')] = 'Dts'
b[b.index[,('$')]] = 'S'

x = list(zip(a,b)) # zip back into an original looking list
```

Comment: the advantage of this approach as compared to `x1 = [(i,j.replace('$','S').replace(':','Dts')) for i,j in x]` is the benefit of using binary search `.index` operator, which works in O(log n) time.

Comment: `.index` is linear search. `b.index[,('$')]` is invalid syntax as well. Also, consider editing your question instead of making a comment.

Comment: yep, you're right:) thanks for pointing this out. Will do in the future

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to understand that tuples are immutable and you should not attempt to modify its contents. It is recommended to convert `x` into a dict like this, so that you can modify the values of the dict because dicts are mutable in Python.

```
In [36]: y = dict(x)

In [37]: y
Out[37]: {'We': 'PRP', "'re": 'VBP', 'really': 'RB$', 'sorry': 'JJ'}
```

Now, you can store all symbols in a variable and look for them in the dict `y`. Whenever, a symbol is found, just replace it with `''` a null value.

```
In [38]: symbols = '$:;?'
In [39]: for k,v in y.items():
    ...:     for symbol in symbols:
    ...:         if symbol in v:
    ...:             v = v.translate({ord(symbol):''})
    ...:             y[k] = v

In [40]: y
Out[40]: {'We': 'PRP', "'re": 'VBP', 'really': 'RB', 'sorry': 'JJ'}
```

Let's add another item to y with a special symbol defined in `symbols`:

```
In [41]: y['test'] = 'ZZ;'

In [42]: y
Out[42]: {'We': 'PRP', "'re": 'VBP', 'really': 'RB', 'sorry': 'JJ', 'test': 'ZZ;'}
```

So, if I enclose the above for loop code in a function `modify_dict` and call, the value for the `test` element will also be modified:

```
In [45]: modify_dict()

In [46]: y
Out[46]: {'We': 'PRP', "'re": 'VBP', 'really': 'RB', 'sorry': 'JJ', 'test': 'ZZ'}
```

To convert it back to a list of tuples:

```
In [55]: z = [(k,v) for k,v in y.items()]

In [56]: z
Out[56]:
[('We', 'PRP'),
 ("'re", 'VBP'),
 ('really', 'RB'),
 ('sorry', 'JJ'),
 ('test', 'ZZ')]
```